# M/M/c queue, but customers might leave the queue due to impatience

Tags: stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

Given a M/M/c queue (Poisson arrival, exponentially distributed service time, c servers). The queue is unlimited in length and operates by first-in-first-out. Each customer who arrives and needs to queue has a patience time T, with a uniform distribution over an interval of [a,b]. That means if the customer has been waiting in queue for T minutes, they will abandon the queue.

I would like to find the average waiting time and the rate of queue abandonment for this queue. I suppose the average waiting time would be similar to a typical M/M/c queue. However I don't know how to approach finding the queue abandonment rate. Is it as simple as figuring out how many customer has a patience time below the average waiting time? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect it's not that simple, since the defection of customers ahead of you in line can affect whether you defect. It's conceivable simulation is your best bet here, but I haven't given it much thought yet. ¶ Incidentally, it might be worth clarifying whether a customer already in a server might still defect if they haven't completed service.

Comment: @BrianTung I'm thinking in terms of say a call center/emergency service, where people in queue aren't aware of others in the queue, or their position in the queue. Once they're connected to an operator, that's considered service

Comment: You can refer to Erlang A model? See chapter 2.1 of [this pdf](https://myweb.ecu.edu/robbinst/PDFs/Erlang%20Compare%20Working%20paper.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

> with a uniform distribution over an interval of [a,b]

For uniform distribution case, I don't know.

For exponential distribution case, the resutl is as follows:

---

[Mandelbaum and Zeltyn 2004](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-29860-1_2) introduce **Erlang A model** in the paper  *Service Engineering in Action: The Palm/Erlang-A Queue, with Applications to Call Centers*

In the Erlang A model $\ M/M/s/k+M\quad$, each
caller posses an exponentially distributed patience time with mean $\theta^{-1}$

Stationary probability distribution:

$$
\begin{aligned}
& P_n=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{\lambda}{\mu}\right)^n P_0, 0 \leq n \leq s . \\
\frac{\lambda^n}{s ! \prod_{j=1}^{n-s}(s \mu+j \theta) \mu^s}, s+1 \leq n \leq k .
\end{array}\right. \\
& P_0=\left(\sum_{n=0}^s \frac{1}{n !}\left(\frac{\lambda}{\mu}\right)^n+\sum_{n=s+1}^k \frac{\lambda^n}{s ! \prod_{j=1}^{n-s}(s \mu+j \theta) \mu^s}\right)^{-1} . \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$

Average queue size:

$$
L_{n}=\sum_{n=0}^{k}np_{n}=(\sum_{n=0}^{s}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}(\frac{\lambda}{m})^{n}+\sum_{n=s+1}^{k}\frac{n\lambda^{n}}{s ! \prod_{j=1}^{n-s}(s \mu+j \theta) \mu^s})P_{0}
$$

Average waiting queue size:

$$
L_q=\sum_{n=s+1}^{k}(n-s)P_{n}=\left ( \sum_{n=s+1}^{k}\frac{(n-s)\lambda^{n}}{s ! \prod_{j=1}^{n-s}(s \mu+j \theta) \mu^s} \right ) P_{0}.
$$

System occupancy rate:

$$
P_B=P_k=\left(\frac{\lambda^k}{s ! \prod_{j=1}^{k-s}(s \mu+j \theta) \mu^m}\right) P_0
$$

Average number of customers rejected due to busy lines:

$$
N_B=P_B \lambda
$$

Number of clients lost due to impatience to give up waiting:

$$
N_L=L_q \theta
$$

Call Loss Ratio:

$$
P_L=\frac{N_B+N_L}{\lambda} =P_B+ \frac{N_L}{\lambda}
$$